# Enable errors in browser when parsing PHP-files

Tags: php, mamp, error-reporting

I recently changed to a MacBook and now use the MAMP-stack for development locally.

In my earlier development environment I always could see informative error-reports when I tried to access a PHP file through a web-browser and an error occurred. With the default installation of MAMP it seems that this feature is disabled, whenever I hit an error I can't see the cause of it, I can't even see a single line informing me that an error occurred.

Not until I start to debug the code in a debugger I can see where the error occurred.

Any idea how error reporting can be turned on?

I tried:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

No effect at all though.

Comment: You need to set this in the php.ini to have an effect for parsing errors.

Comment: have you checked the error reporting level in the php.ini?

Comment: If you checked the `php.ini`, did you look at the _right_ one? Be default there are at least two different `php.ini`s (one for cli and one for apache). Additional some IDEs use an own one.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

reporting level to `E_ALL` and display errors `on` Include the following code at the top of every php file on in an `include` or `require` such as your `config.php`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

Comment: This solved the issue. A more permanent solution was to edit the php.ini file and change the configuration to the following:

    error_reporting  =  E_ALL
    display_errors = On

Answer (score 4):

Try `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`

You'll also want to check a `phpinfo()`, to see if the ini_sets are doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

Or change `"display_errors = Off"` to `"display_errors = On"` in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/conf/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to MAMP settings (eg `localhost:8889/MAMP`)

Click `PHP` Tab

Find `Log errors:` setting

Tick `to screen`

Click `Save`